# Dynamic database modification with Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I am developing a J2EE Web Application with Hibernate ORM and MySQL DB and deploying it in Glassfish application server. User can add records in DB tables through GUI.

**The problem:**
User performs some operation and add a record in a DB Table. 
*But when I am showing data of that particular table, newly added record is not displayed.*
Although DB table shows newly entered record when queried.

I have to redeploy the application to reflect the change in GUI.

This is the code of Servlet  that fetch records from "generateplan" table

```
static Session s1 = null;  static Transaction tx1 = null;

static{
    s1 = HibernateInitilizationSessionFactory.f1.openSession();
    tx1 = s1.beginTransaction();
} 

String queryStmt = "SELECT s FROM GeneratePlan s";

System.out.println("queryStmt:"+queryStmt);

Query q = s1.createQuery(queryStmt);
planList = (ArrayList<GeneratePlan>) q.list();
System.out.println("planList size:" + planList.size());
```

In `HibernateInitilizationSessionFactory` class `SessionFactory` is created.

Comment: Assuming the page executes a fresh database query each time, surely you just need to refresh the page?

Comment: It sounds a lot like something along the line (ORM / Webserver) is caching the results. I can't think of a reason MySQL would be the cause if you can query the table from another connection and the correct results are shown.

Comment: show the servlet or controller, and db access code

Comment: Can You show your code then it will be better to understand for us the problem.

Comment: Agreed with Alex.Ritna, this sounds like caching. Either in a L2 ORM cache or even the browser cache. Try CTRL+F5 (or whatever key combination your particular browser has to do a hard refresh) on the page too to make sure it isn't something as stupid as that.

Comment: Indent your code properly

Comment: Hard refresh is not effective.